# Perl, the module XML::Twig fails tu install. Installing alternative

Tags: xml, perl

Please.
I look forwarts. Wath I can us Alternativly, to works with XML?
I have en win 64 station.

```
cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7034 on perl 5.020002 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int
Work directory is C:\Users\admin/.cpanm/work/1433352517.10892
You have make C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe
You have LWP 6.08
Falling back to Archive::Tar 2.04
Searching XML::Twig () on cpanmetadb ...
XML::Twig is up to date. (3.49)
```

Thanks!
@r

Nota Bene : 11:46 - @Cho..., I m to ... @Sob... I will do. and cam back afternoun. Many Thanks! @r

install (19:02) on \Dwim: XML::Twig and also Number::Format and any moor @r

Comment: How did you try to install the module? What error messages did you get? Please, update the question.

Comment: @Cho.., Thanks for your reply. I Get: cpanm (App::cpanminus) 1.7034 on perl 5.020002 built for MSWin32-x86-multi-thread-64int
Work directory is C:\Users\admin/.cpanm/work/1433352517.10892
You have make C:\STRAWB~1\c\bin\dmake.exe
You have LWP 6.08
Falling back to Archive::Tar 2.04
Searching XML::Twig () on cpanmetadb ...
XML::Twig is up to date. (3.49). @r

Comment: It seems you've already installed XML::Twig.

Comment: @ Cho ..,@Schwern, Thanks for your reply! Padre say's: Can't locate XML/Twig.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Dwimperl/perl/site/lib C:/Dw
imperl/perl/vendor/lib C:/Dwimperl/perl/lib .) at athome.pl line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at athome.pl line 5. So I don't no ..@r

Comment: Do your cpanm and Padre use the same Perl and config?

Comment: @Cho..., Perhaps this is my propleme. \perl; \Dwim; \Straw ..... Wath can I deletet? But i will hold absolutly Padre. Thanks @r

Comment: @Cho... Thanks for your reply. How do, to see my config? Nota Bene can i go to chat? @r

Comment: I can't chat from work, it's blocked.

Comment: Try running `perl -v`. I think it may be that you've got multiple perls installed, and have installed XML::Twig in the 'other' one. The easy workaround is `perl -MCPAN -e shell` `install XML::Twig` - which will run the 'right' perl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a failure.  It's exactly what it told you at the end there.

```
XML::Twig is up to date. (3.49)
```

You already have XML::Twig installed and it is [the latest version, 3.49](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig).

Comment: The one thing I might think - if they've got Strawberry and Active perl installed, and have installed the module in the 'other one'.

Comment: @Sob..., Thanks for your reply. At your suggestion i have doing this yesterday. But not success .... I sing the best is I have all to deinslling and start an news and only \Straw? @r

Comment: @To all, I have ClinUp the resau and all works perfect! Thanks to You @r Nota Bene This probleme is solved!